# K largest elements in an array complexity

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, data-structures, heap

I am using a max heap to find the k largest elements in an array as follows:

1) I have Build a Min Heap MH of the first k elements (arr[0] to arr[k-1]) of the given array. O(k)

2) For each element, after the kth element (arr[k] to arr[n-1]), compare it with root of MH.

……a) If the element is greater than the root then make it root and call heapify for MH

……b) Else ignore it.

// The step 2 is O((n-k))

3) Finally, MH has k largest elements and root of the MH is the kth largest element.

I have searched over the net and the complexity for 2nd step is showing me O(n-k)logk which i think should be (n-k)*O(k) if we build the heap using bottom up approach.Because at every step i am just replacing the root whenever a greater element is found. And the complexity to heapify an array of k elements is O(k)

Am i wrong please clarify. I just need to know if i am thinking correct?

My method is as follows :

```
private static void createMinHeap(int[] arr) {

        for (int i = arr.length / 2; i >= 0; i--) {
            restoreDown(arr, i);
        }

    }

    private static void restoreDown(int[] arr, int i) {

        int left = (2 * i) + 1;
        int right = (2 * i) + 2;
        int num = arr[i];

        while (right <= arr.length) {

            if (num <= arr[right] && num <= arr[left]) {
                arr[i] = num;
                return;
            } else if (arr[right] < arr[left]) {
                arr[i] = arr[right];
                i = right;
            } else {
                arr[i] = arr[left];
                i = left;
            }

            left = (2 * i) + 1;
            right = (2 * i) + 2;
        }

        if (left == arr.length - 1 && arr[left] < num) {
            arr[i] = arr[left];
            i = left;
        }

        arr[i] = num;

    }
```

Comment: Rebalancing is log N, not N.

Comment: You might consider asking in CS or Theoretical CS or Algorithms. SO is more about program codes.

Comment: The complexity to heapify an array of k element is O(log(k)) I think. In the worst case you heapify only one of the subtrees for each node going from top, don't you?

Answer (score 3):

Your reasoning is almost correct, however with the heap of size `k`, heapify operation takes `O(log k)`. Therefore, total complexity is `O(n log k)`. Why? In the worst case, you should execute heapify for each of `n-k` remaining elements. Since `k` is fixed and `n` can be arbitrary large, that is `O(n)` steps, which finally gives `O(n log k)`.

**See also:**

- [Heap sort](http://geeksquiz.com/heap-sort/)

Comment: For `k` a constant, `log k` would also be a constant. So shouldn’t the final result be `O(n)` for fixed values of `k`?

Comment: @pjs if `k` is specified in advance (e.g. `k = 2`), then of course, `log k` is also a constant. However, it can depend on `n` (e.g. `k = n/2`), so it has to be included as a variable in the complexity analysis as well.

Answer (score -1):

If we have an unsorted array, then heapify operation gets called n/2-1 times.
Heapify operation takes O(log n) time. So total time here is: O (n log n).

Now, extraction operation happens n times and each time , heapify operation gets called. Time taken is: O (n log n).

So, total time is : O(n log n) + O(n log n) = O(n log n).

Comment: Your analysis is incorrect for the algorithm specified in the question.

Answer (score -3):

The [Selection algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm) allows you to find the kth element, or the k largest elements in an array in O(n) time.

Comment: How does this answers my question?

Comment: @user2565192 what part of "the k largest elements in an array in O(n) time"  (quoted from my answer) you don't understand ?  Did you not ask what is the complexity of finding "K largest elements in an array" (quoted from question) ?

Comment: @JimMischel   I guess you missed the part where the question is about the complexity, rather then the efficiency of a real world implementation. Using the selection algorithm (specifically quick-select) gives you a worst case complexity of O(n), which is better than a heap based solution in asymptotical complexity.

Comment: The O(n) estimate for quickselect is for the average case, not worst case, which is O(n**2), just like for quicksort.